# change place of last column but getting new line

Tags: awk

I have a file separated by \t.

```
header text with many lines
V    F    A    B
10    30    26    42
14    33    25    45
16    32    23    43
18    37    22    48
```

I want to change the 3rd column by the 4th and vice versa. I'm using

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n";
    OFS="\t";
    record=0;
};
record {
    a = $4;
    $4 = $3;
    $3 = a;
};
$1=="V" {
    record=1
};
{
    print $0
};
'
}
```

Instead of just changing the position of the columns, column 3 also has the line break of the original 4th column:

```
header text with many lines
V    F    A    B
10    30    42
    26
14    33    45
    25
16    32    43
    23
18    37    48
    22
```

How can I prevent this in order to get?

```
header text with many lines
V    F    A    B
10    30    42    26
14    33    45    25
16    32    43    23
18    37    48    22
```

Comment: Are you sure your `RS` is just `\n`. Might there be a carriage return in there too like `\r\n`? That's very likely if this file was created in windows.

Comment: I had just solved it by writing `a=gensub(/([0-9\.]*).*/, "\\1", 1, $5)`, but then I tried your suggestion and it works in a much better and cleaner way. Indeed, the data file was generated in windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, using usual method of storing 1 field's value to a variable and then exchanging the value of 4th field to 3rd field, at last putting 4th field value as variable value(could say swapping values using a variable).

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} {val=$3;$3=$4;$4=val} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, this messy sed:

```
sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+)([[:blank:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)([[:space:]]*)$/\3\2\1\4/' file
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#         3rd column        tab       4th column    optional whitespce
```